# I'm trying to use jquery's clone() to create multiple sprite-like DIV's, crashes browser

Tags: jquery

After finding the latest version of Crafty's game API seems to fail in IE8, I thought I would get back to my friend JQuery, to create a few simple board games.

I started off with 3 DIV's, a black tile, a white tile, and blank tile, set Display:none

Then I thought to clone the blank tile to the dimensions of whatever board game I desired.
Using a simple double for loop, when set to 8x8 it crashes the browser, when set to 2x2 it is slow, can someone suggest me ways to improve the performance?

The CSS:

```
<style>
    .white {
        position:relative;
        width:57px;
        height:57px;
    }
    .white img {
        position:absolute;
        width:171px;
        height:57px;
        left:-57px;
        top:0px;
        clip:rect(0px, 114px, 57px, 57px); 
     }
    .blank {
        position:relative;
        width:57px;
        height:57px;
     }
    .blank img {
        position:absolute;
        width:171px;
        height:57px;
        left:-114px;
        top:0px;
        clip:rect(0px, 171px, 57px, 114px); 
     }
    .black {
        position:relative;
        width:57px;
        height:57px;
     }
    .black img {
        position:absolute;
        width:171px;
        height:57px;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        clip:rect(0px, 57px, 57px, 0px); 
     }
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="white" style="display:none">
   <img src="images/sprites.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="black" style="display:none">
   <img src="images/sprites.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="blank" style="display:none">
   <img src="images/sprites.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="start">
</div>
```

The jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {     
    B_W = 456;
    B_H = 456;
    B_X = 8;
    B_Y = 8;
    SQ_W = 57;
    SQ_H = 57;

    var i=0;
    var j=0;

    for(i = 0; i < B_X; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < B_Y; j++) {
                $('.blank').clone()
                    .insertAfter('.start')
                    .css({
                        'position':'absolute', 
                        'top' : j * SQ_H + 'px', 
                        'left' : i * SQ_W + 'px', 
                        'display' : 'block'
                    });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you change the elements to be `position: relative` and float them you won't need to position each one individually. This will then remove the need to have the `css()` call for each cloned element.

Comment: Great that will certainly improve it, but if I have a board game that is a good 300 squares, clone() still crashes. In the past I would just use PHP to fill out everything x 300, it became way too large!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second best thing you can do is add the position and display attributes as a css style, and add the image as a background to the DIV, for example:

```
<style>
.blank
{
   position:absolute;
   display:block;
   width:8px;
   height:8px;
   background: url('images/sprites.png')
}
</style>
```

and then "play" with the background positioning. You can do this like so for the next 8x8 pixel portion of your sprites png:

```
style="background-position: 8px 0px; "
```

Also, have a template DIV at the start, which has an ID=blank instead of class=blank, and set the selector to:

```
$('#blank')
```

Best solution would be to use the canvas element though!

Comment: Right, I was going to do something similar and get PHP to fill out all the CSS for the different game board sizes, but I like the idea of keeping things small and modular, must be IE8 compatible, and I'm wondering why clone() is crashing the browser.

Comment: You can get canvas on IE8 with modernizer, as for the crashing part I'm positive the solution above won't crash for you. You were copying ALL the divs which had a class="blank" each time over and over again on top of themselves. Ie, on the first iteration, the $(.'blank').clone() will create THREE instead of one clones

Comment: No problem! Just make sure to upvote and/or select as answer the answers you think help you

Comment: So this was the fix. I gave blank tile an id of "n0" and then incremented the cloned id by 1 via attr();   $('#N0').clone().insertAfter('.start').css({'position':'absolute', 'top' : j*SQ_H+'px', 'left' : i*SQ_W+'px', 'display' : 'block'}).attr('id','#N'+((i*B_X)+j+1));

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment about utilising CSS where possible for the common styles, and using `float: left` instead of working out each elements' absolute position: Try this:

**Edit**
Updated to allow you to change grid size dynamically.

HTML

```
<div id="white" class="block">
   <img src="images/sprites.png" alt="">
</div>

<div id="black" class="block">
   <img src="images/sprites.png" alt="">
</div>

<div id="blank" class="block">
   <img src="images/sprites.png" alt="">
</div>

<div id="block-container">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    float: left;    
}
#white, #black, #blank { display: none; }
.white { background-color: #FFF; }
.black { background-color: #000; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    blockCountX = 8;
    blockCountY = 8;
    blockWidth = 57;
    blockHeight = 57;

    $("#block-container").css({ width: blockCountX * blockWidth + "px", height: blockCountY * blockHeight + "px" });
    $(".block").css({ width: blockWidth  + "px", height: blockHeight + "px" });

    var counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < blockCountX; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < blockCountY; j++) {
            var isWhite = (counter + i) % 2;
            var selector = isWhite ? "white" : "black";
            $("#" + selector).clone().attr('id', 'block_' + counter).addClass(selector).appendTo('#block-container')
            counter++;
        }
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle to show it works**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/yXHGk/5/)